# In my React app I cannot get the removePlayer method to be passed to the Player component as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I am able to see the name, key and Id props when I inspect the element, but not removePlayer. When I inspect the element I do the the removePlayer prop but its value is empty.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [
    {name: 'player1', id: 1},
    {name: 'player2', id: 2},
    {name: 'player3', id: 3},
    {name: 'player4', id: 4 }
  ]
  }

  removePlayer = (id) => {
    this.setState( prevState => {
      return {
        players: prevState.players.filter( p => p.id !== id)
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scoreboard">
        <Header title="Scoreboard" totalPlayers={this.state.players.length}/>
        {this.state.players.map( player => {
         return (
           <Player
             name={player.name}
             id={player.id}
             removePlayer={this.removePlayer}
             key={String(player.id)}>
           </Player>)
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: here you are passing removePlayer as function So,will get your removePlayer as function in your Player component

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. It would be helpful if you can replicate it in Sandbox.

Comment: If by 'inspect the element' you mean inspecting it via something like devtools, you won't see `removePlayer`, props aren't usually rendered to the DOM, only special props like `id` and `name`. If you want to see what's actually being passed to `Player`, add something like `console.log(this.props)` in `Player`'s `componentDidMount` or `render` function.

Comment: That will be available in the props of Player component. You have to call it either as `this.props.removePlayer(idtoberemoved)` in a class component or `props.removePlayer(idtoberemoved)` in a functional component.